# squid crashes when connecting to facebook

Tags: squid

I'm using squid to build an http proxy server. It works well until I tried to connect to https://www.facebook.com/ on my client (Mac OS X 10.10). Every time when I try to connect to Facebook, an "cannot connect to proxy server" error is raised, and the other sites which were previously accessible reports the same error too. I have to stop squid and start it again after a few seconds. It seems that when connecting to Facebook, the squid crashes. The same problem is also with Twitter. Does anyone knows what's wrong? Thank you!

Here is my `squid.conf` file:

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
#http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
#http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
auth_param basic program /usr/bin/basic_ncsa_auth /var/squid/etc/password
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm My Proxy Caching Domain
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
acl mall proxy_auth REQUIRED
#acl mall src 0.0.0.0/0
http_access allow mall

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 8899

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

---

The squid log says:

`1442643581.775      0 114.255.40.16 TCP_DENIED/407 3757 CONNECT www.facebook.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html`

run "systemctl status squid.service":

```
squid.service - Squid caching proxy
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/squid.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2015-09-18 17:45:01 EDT; 8h ago
  Process: 1213 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/squid -k shutdown -f $SQUID_CONF (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1220 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/squid $SQUID_OPTS -f $SQUID_CONF (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1215 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/squid/cache_swap.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1223 (squid)
   CGroup: /system.slice/squid.service
           ├─1223 /usr/sbin/squid -f /etc/squid/squid.conf
           ├─1225 (squid-1) -f /etc/squid/squid.conf
           ├─1226 (logfile-daemon) /var/log/squid/access.log
           └─1227 (basic_ncsa_auth) /var/squid/etc/password

Sep 18 17:45:01 cosmo systemd[1]: Starting Squid caching proxy...
Sep 18 17:45:01 cosmo systemd[1]: Started Squid caching proxy.
Sep 18 17:45:01 cosmo squid[1223]: Squid Parent: will start 1 kids
Sep 18 17:45:01 cosmo squid[1223]: Squid Parent: (squid-1) process 1225 started
```

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for that. I have checked my logs and didn't find anything wrong. I have updated my config file and pasted the logs...

Comment: Run Squid directly from the command line with debugging enabled and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem running Squid 2.7 a couple years ago... a configuration that worked fine on one computer did this on a second computer.  I still don't know the cause, but changing the

```
 # Squid normally listens to port 3128
  http_port 8899
```

back to the default port `3128` seems to solve it (or at least it did for me).